# Jquery event executing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm realy struggling on a peace of code by hours:

```
    $('#property_image_uploader').on('submit',function(e) {
         var formData = new FormData(this);
         $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url: $(this).attr('action'),
             data:formData,
             cache:false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             success:function(data){
             $.ajax({
                 contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
                 , method: 'post'
                 , url: 'property_info_box.php'
                 , data: {id: parseInt(data)}
                 , success: function(page){
                     $('#property_info_box', parent.document).html(page);
                     return false; }
                 });
             },
             error: function(data){ console.log(data); }
        });
    });

    $("#property_image_chooser").on("change", function(e){
        $("#property_image_uploader").submit();
    });
```

The problem is that everytime $('#property_image_chooser') changes, the $('#property_image_uploader') submition is fired twice. I've tried to place e.preventDefault() and e.stopImmediatePropagation() in everywhere inside this two functions and THIS problem went away, but then, the page that is loaded on second ajax call freezes, and no button can be trigged anymore...

Comment: Before we go on with searching what is going on did you tried what @Dez suggest?

Comment: Never mind I see that you have update your question and you did it. So please update your code too. To avoid this kind of misunderstanding.

Comment: The problem with second ajax freezing is due because *return false;* line. You don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the problem is solved by adding the e.preventDefault() at the submition and removing the 'return false' on the the second ajax call. The final code looks like this:

```
$('#property_image_uploader').on('submit',function(e) {
     var formData = new FormData(this);
     $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url: $(this).attr('action'),
         data:formData,
         cache:false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         success:function(data){
         $.ajax({
             contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
             , method: 'post'
             , url: 'property_info_box.php'
             , data: {id: parseInt(data)}
             , success: function(page){
                 $('#property_info_box', parent.document).html(page); }
             });
         },
         error: function(data){ console.log(data); }
    });
});

$("#property_image_chooser").on("change", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#property_image_uploader").submit();
});
```

Thank you all very much...